# Blurry text on EditText on SonyEricsson phones - Android

Tags: android, textview

I updated my app for Android 4.0 to make it more futureproof,
after the update, i started to get reports from SE-users that their edittext and textviews are all blurry, the FONT is blurry (which makes me think that this is a SE-problem).

Even if i change the font, it is still blurry.

Does anyone know a solution or have experience the same?

Can't show you any screenshots of this...

Regards.

Comment: I've had one of our team report this issue, What is interesting is 'some' of the fragments have blurry text - some don't. If I solve it I shall let you know.

Comment: FYI - I've had this reported on Samsung SII pre ICS. So its not limited to Sony's

Answer (score 2):

This is a styling issue.

I had my edit text inherit the Holo theme which caused the text to blur on pre ICS devices, this may be pre HoneyComb, but I haven't been able to check.

values/styles.xml

```
<!-- Base style for the edit text, api dependant -->
<style name="Widget.EditBase" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText"></style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml

```
<!-- Base Style for the edit text -->
<style name="Widget.EditBase" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"></style>
```

This fixed it instantly for me - v11 being HoneyComb 3.0 which should be fine as the Holo theme is available from then onwards.

Can't explain why, but assuming it must be with the `Widget.Holo.EditText` style pointing to the wrong resource pre ICS/HC.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: HI Chris! When you say pre-ICS you mean Honeycomb also or only pre HC? I wouldve thought always a bad idea to use a theme not present in your min supported platform without a fallback in any case!

Comment: I didn't test on HC devices as I don't have any samsung HC devices, My guessing probably not as HC has the Holo theme. But I can't test. I'll update the answer for brevity in any case. Cheers.

Comment: Thank's a lot ! I got the same issue and spliting my styles.xml in 2 version, one with the holo theme and one without works like a charm. For me this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue affecting different phones.  What my problem was is that my custom theme was using a parent theme from ICS which wasn't available on older phones.  My solution was to have a `values-v11/themes.xml` for ICS devices and `values/themes.xml` for older android phones.